# How do I reference a word document in my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to use a word file in my visual studio project for edits and return the file.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document tempDoc = null;
try
{
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Application wordApp = new Application();

    //I have a copy on C: and this works.
    object useFileName = "C:\\WordFile.doc";

    object readOnly = false;
    object isVisible = false;
    wordApp.Visible = false;
    tempDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref useFileName, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing);
    ...
    }
    return tempDoc;
```

How do I reference the word document in my project (Content/Documents/WordFile)?

Comment: @Freeman: because of the `ref` parameter modifier that requires reference variable I imagine

Comment: your imagination speaks the truth.

Comment: Do not use Office Interop in an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using `Server.MapPath` which specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.

```
Server.MapPath("~/Content/Documents/WordFile")
```

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get the location on the executing code from
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

Alternatively place the document location in the config file.